# Calculate prefix expression unix

Tags: c, unix, prefix

I need to write a multi-process prefix expressions parser and evaluator.

Given a prefix expression such as the following on standard input
for instance: `(+ (* (+ 2 4) 5) (- (- 6 7) 8))`.

The program should read each sub-expressions in a forked process.

The parent process must wait until the child process has finished reading its sub-expression, and continue from there.

It is not illegal to use scanf or printf functions.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? What have worked? What haven't worked? Oh, and you might want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Tell your professor, or whoever gave you this assignment, that it's quite unreasonable. Nobody would ever fork a process to read a "sub-expression", which in your example might be as little as a single decimal digit. Truly weird, even for homework.

Comment: Send your professor this pic http://www.dumpaday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/dog-chews-up-computer-funny-pictures1.jpg

Comment: this is my first assignment, I realy dont know what to do and how to start this

Comment: Ignore the fact that you have to create processes for a minute. Can you write a program that parses a prefix expression by using a function that calls itself recursively? Start there.

Answer (score 0):

Totally useless, but maybe fun.

1. You start by doing this in one process only.
2. Add that multiprocess stuff.

As a hint, I show you how to do this in C++.  You have to translate this into C yourself:

```
int read_sequence()
{
    int y;
    if ((cin>>ws).peek() == '('){
        cin.ignore( 1 );
        char op = cin.get();
        y = read_sequence();
        while ((cin>>ws).peek() != ')'){
            int b = read_sequence();
            y = op == '+' ? y + b
                : op == '-' ? y - b
                : op == '*' ? y*b
                : y / b;
        }
        cin.ignore( 1 );
    } else {
        cin >> y;
    }
    return y;
}
```